# Remove space between table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, html-email

I'm building an html email template and need to remove the spacing between table rows, but need to keep the cellspacing at 10px. You will see in the example blue title bars and the spacing beneath them. Is there any way to isolate those table rows using CSS and remove this?

HTML: http://www.tailwatersflyfishing.com/email/template/new.html

Comment: Your example is not very clear however I would recommend you remove cell spacing from table and separate tables using css margin and padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a new attribuut (cellspacing) to the table holding the blue title

```
<table width="670" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
```

Is it possible you are confusing cellpadding and padding with cellspacing, since i can't see any cellspacing attribuut to the table tags...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, semantically, tables should not be used for layout-- they should be used to display tabular data... Secondly, a fix (it's not a great fix, but it works) is to essentially disable table functionality:

```
table, tbody, tr {
    display: block;
}
```

Look into switching your headlines to h2 tags or something-- maybe an element that is actually semantically created to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you are targeting a wide range of email clients, then the only option here is to use tables for layout purposes...

Comment: Ah yea, I've never designed for email. Regardless, there's still a fix in there :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use CSS call beacause mailer doesn't accept them (Lotus, Outllok 2007, ...)

For spaces you can use a spacer image (a 1x1 px transparent gif) to get them looks right

the font-style:0 correct a blank space in hotmail on Firefox render.

You need also to put a display:block for all your image and specify a height and width for both the image and the TD where it apears.